# Elastalert : Cluster health notification

Tags: elastalert

I don't know elastalert much.
I just wanted to know whether it is possible to get notification when cluster status is RED using elastalert.

Thank you

Comment: If you are ingesting logs of your Elasticsearch into Elasticsearch itself, I bet you could write a rule to query those logs to alert when the cluster status is red.

Answer (score 1):

its possible. but you need to access it via the cluster health query.
sample:

```
input{
    exec {
       curl -u <username>:<password> <elasticsearch-ip:port>/_cluster/health
       codec => rubydebug
       type => cluster-health
    }
}
output {
    if "health" in [type] {
        elasticsearch{ 
            index => "cluster-health-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            hosts => ["elasticsearch-host:port"]
        }
    }
}
```

if you have filters that are not parsing it add a filter with `if [type] == "cluster-health"` section to filter and parse it as json. 
this gives you basic details. though you may need to update the field mapping of status.. at least i am facing issue and you have readily availability. Now you can wuery as you normally would under elastalert.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they don't have this functionality out of the box yet. But there are some hacky ways to achieve it https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert/issues/903
They recommend to use Marvel instead.

Answer (score -1):

No as far as I know.

Current Elastalert [documentation](https://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ruletypes.html#common-configuration-options) state that the index field is mandatory in the rule .yaml file.

The current way elasticsearch cluster provide health status is via the [healthapi](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-health.html) so no index is available for querying.

Comment: did you try logstash elasticsearch input plugin to run the cluster health query and output to elasicsearch with some index name? i think that will create the health index